# Reordering columns (fields) in a ADO Recordset

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I have a classic asp webpage written in vbscript that outputs the results from a third-party stored procedure. My user wants the page to display the columns of data in a different order than they come in from the database.  **Is there an easy and safe way to re-order the columns in an ADO recordset?**

I did not write this page and cannot change the SP. 
What is the minimum change I can make here to get the job done and not risk screwing up all the other stuff in the page?

The code looks something like

```
dim Conn, strSQL, RS
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open ServerName

Set strSQL = "EXEC storedProc @foo = " & Request("fooParam")
'This stored procedure returns a date column, an arbitrary '
' number of data columns, and two summation columns.  We '
' want the two summation columns to move so they appear '
' immediately after the data column '

Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
RS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RS.CursorType = adOpenStatic
RS.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
RS.Open strSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

dim A

' ----- '
' Insert some code here to move the columns of the RS around '
' to suit the whim of my user '
' ----- '


' Several blocks of code that iterate over the RS and display it various ways '
RS.MoveFirst
For A = 0 To RS.Fields.Count -1
    ' do stuff '
Next

...

RS.MoveFirst
For A = 0 To RS.Fields.Count -1
    ' do more stuff '
Next

RS.Close : Set RS = Nothing
Conn.Close : Set Conn = Nothing
```

Comment: With properly written code, the order of the columns in the resultset should not matter at all, you should not be using positional indexing, instead use named indexes.

Comment: The SP returns an arbitrary number of columns the names of which are likewise arbitrary.

Comment: So the ordering is by column type?  The data columns being arbitrary and the summation columns being arbitrarily named as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the column names, then set up an ordering for them:

```
dim ColumnNames
set ColumnNames = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
For A = 0 To RS.Fields.Count -1
  ColumnNames.Add A, RS.Fields(A).Name
Next
```

Here, ColumnNames holds the name of the column to use for each position.  Applying whatever rules make sense, you can now change the ordering like so:

```
'' swap order of columns 1 and 2
dim temp
temp = ColumnNames.item( 1 )
ColumnNames.item( 1 ) = ColumnNames.item( 2 )
ColumnNames.item( 2 ) = temp
```

Finally, to get the new order, print as follows:

```
For A = 0 To RS.Fields.Count -1
  Response.write( ColumnNames.item( A ) )
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to reorder them? If you KNOW that the output follows a certain pattern:

Date, Data1, DataN, Sum1, Sum2

You have Fields.Count to let you decide how many DataN columns to display, and at which index Sum1 and Sum are located.